# Django: how to load a fixture that contains Decimal

Tags: django

I want to load a fixture that contains decimal. The fixture are in json `"salarymax": "58,689.54",` Following the documentation of [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/), I added to true these value:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = True
```

Here is a snippet of the fixture:

```
{
    "fields": {
        ...#shortened
        "pub_date": "2015-12-23",
        "salarymax": "58,689.54",
        "salarymin": "50,164.66",
        "salarytype": "annually"
    },
    "model": "emplois.job",
    "pk": 1
},
```

here is my model (for the moment only `salarymax` is in **Decimal**)

## Create your models here.

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Job(models.Model):
    #...shortened
    joburl = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    expirydate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    salarymax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, localize=True)
    salarymin = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    salarytype = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True) 
    ...
```

`python manage.py loaddata fixtures/data.json` here is an excerpt of the error:

```
  File "/home/guinslyziho/development/public/tutorial/django_website_documentation/ottawacitijobs/new_app/ottawacityjobs/emplois/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Job(models.Model):
  File "/home/guinslyziho/development/public/tutorial/django_website_documentation/ottawacitijobs/new_app/ottawacityjobs/emplois/models.py", line 34, in Job
    salarymax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, localize=True)
  File "/home/guinslyziho/development/public/tutorial/django_website_documentation/env_python_3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1484, in __init__
    super(DecimalField, self).__init__(verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'localize'
```

Comment: argument `localize` is used for forms, not models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argument localize is used for forms, not models.

```
class Job(models.Model):
    #...shortened
    joburl = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    expirydate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    salarymax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    salarymin = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    salarytype = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True) 
    ...
```

Proper format of decimal numbers in fixtures are:

**float**

```
{
    "fields": {
        ...#shortened
        "pub_date": "2015-12-23",
        "salarymax": 58689.54,
        "salarymin": "50,164.66",
        "salarytype": "annually"
    },
    "model": "emplois.job",
    "pk": 1
},
```

**formatted string**

```
{
    "fields": {
        ...#shortened
        "pub_date": "2015-12-23",
        "salarymax": '58689.54',
        "salarymin": "50,164.66",
        "salarytype": "annually"
    },
    "model": "emplois.job",
    "pk": 1
},
```

In this case string cannot be localized.

Try this:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(58100.23)
Decimal('58100.2300000000032014213502407073974609375')
>>> Decimal('58100.23')
Decimal('58100.23')
>>> Decimal('58,100.23')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    Decimal('58,100.23')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_pydecimal.py", line 597, in __new__
    "Invalid literal for Decimal: %r" % value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_pydecimal.py", line 4032, in _raise_error
    raise error(explanation)
decimal.InvalidOperation: Invalid literal for Decimal: '58,100.23'
```